# Symfony 4 - How to set entity id for route in redirect after form submit

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

Building Symfony 4.1 app. In my ProfileController ...

I have a booking_new method with form to create a new booking:

```
/**
 * @Route("/profile/booking/new", name="profile_booking_new")
 */
public function booking_new(EntityManagerInterface $em, Request $request)
{

    $form = $this->createForm(BookingFormType::class);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        /** @var @var Booking $booking */
        $booking = $form->getData();
        $booking->setUser($this->getUser());

        $em->persist($booking);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('profile_booking_show');

    }

    return $this->render('profile/bookings/booking_new.html.twig',[
        'bookingForm' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Then I have a booking_show method to render single booking pages with route set to booking id:

```
/**
 * @Route("/profile/booking/{id}", name="profile_booking_show")
 */
public function booking_show(BookingRepository $bookingRepo, $id)
{
    /** @var Booking $booking */
    $booking = $bookingRepo->findOneBy(['id' => $id]);

    if (!$booking) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(sprintf('There is no booking for id "%s"', $id));
    }

    return $this->render('profile/bookings/booking_show.html.twig', [
        'booking' => $booking,
    ]);
}
```

After the booking is created I want to redirect user to the show booking view with the correct id.

Run server and get this error ...

```
ERROR: Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate a URL for route "profile_booking_show".
```

I understand the error but how do I fix it? How do I set the id of the booking just created without needing to query for the id?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once the new entity is persited & flushed, you can use it like:

```
 $em->persist($booking);
 $em->flush();

 return $this->redirectToRoute('profile_booking_show', ['id' => $bookig->getId()]);
```

Comment: @Etshy Thank you both, each answer was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html), you have to add an array of parameters as second argument

`return $this->redirectToRoute('profile_booking_show', ['id'=>$id]);`

Comment: Ok I'll try that. PS is it best practice to redirect to the booking_show page or the bookings_list page? or is it up to developer preference?

Comment: I don't think there a best practice about that. it's up to the developper's/client's preferences.
@G1.3 that was just an example, of course he need to take `$booking->getId()` or whatever the get id method is.

Comment: @Etshy okay. I thought the blocking point of the question was the id retrieving ;)

Comment: So I would place $booking->getId() directly after the flush()?